# How can I create EventHandler class with typescript?

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to migrate my project from a javascript to a typescript and have a problem with migrating class for handling events.

To avoid double describing options for an add/remove event listener we use a wrapper like this:

```
constructor() {
  this.windowResizeHandler = new MyEventHandler(
    target: window,
    event: 'resize',
    handler: e => this.handleResize_(e),
    options: {passive: true, capturing: true},
  );
} 

connectedCallback() {
  this.windowResizeHandler.add();
}

disconnectedCallback() {
  this.windowResizeHandler.remove();
}
```

Now i don't know how to write this in typescript without loosing information about events typing. For example:

```
document.createElement('button').addEventListener('click', e => {
  // Here e is MouseEvent.
});
```

But if I write my wrapper like:

```
interface EventHandlerParams {
  readonly target: EventTarget;
  readonly event: Event;
  readonly listener: (e: Event) => void;
  readonly params: AddEventListenerOptions;
}

export class EventHandler {
  public constructor(params: EventHandlerParams) {}
}
```

Then I loose typings:

```
new MyEventHandler(
  target: document.createElement('button'),
  event: 'click',
  handler: e => { /* Here e is just Event not MouseEvent */ },
  options: {passive: true, capturing: true},
);
```

Is there any options for me to use event typings from `lib.dom.d.ts` here?

Answer (score 2):

There is a type in `lib.dom.ts` that contains mappings between all event names and event argument types. It's called `WindowEventMap`.

So we can for example write the following:

```
interface EventHandlerParams<T extends keyof WindowEventMap> {
    readonly target: EventTarget;
    readonly event: T;
    readonly options: AddEventListenerOptions;
    readonly listener: (e: WindowEventMap[T]) => void
}

export class EventHandler<T extends keyof WindowEventMap> {
    public constructor(params: EventHandlerParams<T>) { }
}


new EventHandler({
    target: document.createElement('button'),
    event: 'click',
    options: { passive: true },
    listener: e => { e.x /* e is MouseEvent */ }
});
```

`EventHandlerParams` is now generic and will capture the event name as the type parameter `T`. We also made `EventHandler` generic, and it's `T` will be determined by the prams passed to it. Armed with `T` (which will contain the string literal type for the event) we can get access to the actual param type for the event from `WindowEventMap` and use it in our listener signature.

**Note** I think before 3.0 the arguments to listener might not be inferred to the correct type (they might be inferred to `any`). If you run into this issue let me know and I can provide the before 3.0 version.

Comment: Thx for so quick reply.

I've thought about this solution but I will have to provide several dozen of `EventHandlerParams` interfaces for each `*EventMap` inteface. Like `interface EventHandlerWindowParams<T extends keyof WindowEventMap>`, `interface EventHandlerHtmlElementParams<T extends keyof HTMLElementEventMap>` and so on.

Comment: @Yavanosta So you would like based on the type of the target to get the apropriate events ?

Comment: I'm looking for something like this: `interface EventHandlerHtmlElementParams<TTarget extends EventTaget, TEvent> { target: TTarget, event: TEvent extends key of SomeMagicMapping[TTarget]; listener(event: SomeMagicMapping[TTarget][TEvent]) }`. But seems there is no reusable link between, for example, `HTMLElement` and `HTMLElementEventMap`

Comment: @Yavanosta We can extract a map of all event names a type can take. `type EventKeys<T extends EventTarget> =  T extends { 
        addEventListener: {
            (type: infer K, listener: any): void;
            (type: string, listener:  EventListenerOrEventListenerObject): void;
        }
    } ? K: never;` But there is no way back to the original event map they came from.. We could have an intersection of all event maps and index into that.. but this exhaustive intersection would have to be manually maintained and two events with the same name might have different parameter types

Comment: But WindowEventMap is not exported and not declared in lib.dom.ts =(

Answer (score 0):

@titian-cernicova-dragomir I'm for something like this (DOES NOT WORK):

```
interface Mapping {
  [Window]: WindowEventMap;
  [HTMLElement]: HTMLElementEventMap;
}

interface EventHandlerParams<TTarget extends keyof Mapping,
                             TEventName extends keyof Mapping[TTarget],
                             TEvent extends Mapping[TTarget][TEventName]> {
  readonly event: TEventName;
  readonly listener: (event: TEvent) => void;
  readonly params?: AddEventListenerOptions;
  readonly target: TTarget;
}


export class EventHandler<TTarget extends keyof Mapping,
                          TEventName extends keyof Mapping[TTarget],
                          TEvent extends Mapping[TTarget][TEventName]> {
  public constructor(params: EventHandlerParams<TTarget, TEventName, TEvent>) {}
}
```

But can't use this because types can not be interface properties and there is no any other options to provide constraint for `TTarget`.